# UIImageView inside UICollectionViewCell image won't fit properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, iosdeployment

I have a UICollectionView and each UICollectionViewCell is a custom class with a UIImageView

```
@interface MyCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *image;
@end
```

Then I have an image I would like to fit inside the imageview. But I can't get the image to fit properly inside the image view. Here's the image. [image] those are the exact dimensions, I think that's a 36x36 but essentially I don't want the size to matter I just want it to scale down and fit regardless of the size. The dimensions of the UIImageView in the storyboard is 59x54 ( I know this can change depending on how the screen wants to display the cells so again size should not be relevant) These are the current display settings for the view in storyboard [image] And my UICollectionView delegate code

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{
    return 3;
}
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 3;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    MyCollectionViewCell* cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell.image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"avocado"]];

    return cell;
}
```

The result looks like this [image] So you see how the edge is slightly cut off. I did read a few other answers of trying `[cell.image setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];` but that didn't work either. Does anyone have a solution for this? The UIImageView is fit inside the UICollectionViewCell like so [image]

The outer blue line is the UICollectionViewCell and the inner blue line is the UIImageView.

Comment: What constraints have you set on your image view?

Comment: My image view is set to fit inside the UIICollectionViewCell I will update my answer showing an image of it. Is that what you mean by constraints?

Comment: It looks like you might not have added any constraints. Try adding top, leading, bottom, and trailing constraints between the image view and the cell so that the image view is sized correctly when the cell changes size - otherwise the image view will remain this size seen in the storyboard even if the cell is a different size. You will also for sure need to change your image view's `Content Mode` (seen in your storyboard image) from `Scale to Fill` to `Aspect Fit` in order for the image to scale without stretching. Try making those changes and let me know what that does.

Comment: Woah! Yes that worked. I set the constraints as you said and set the content mode to Aspect Fit and now it's displaying correctly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you add top, leading, bottom, and trailing constraints between the image view and the cell so that the image view is sized correctly when the cell changes size - otherwise the image view will remain this size seen in the storyboard even if the cell changes size.

You will also for sure need to change your image view's `Content Mode` (seen in your storyboard image) from `Scale to Fill` to `Aspect Fit` in order for the image to scale without stretching.